# ASCII 3D Text looks glitchy when used for a HTML Website

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, web-testing

I am using ASCII 3D Text for my website and it looks quite glitchy, this problem does not occour on other websites.
Example 1:
[As you can see, there are glitchy lines on my website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6HH8k.png)

Example 2:
Another website with the same text but no glitchy lines are visible.
[No glitchy lines present](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tm2ra.png)

The text in particular (glitchy lines may be visible):
██████╗░░█████╗░░██████╗░██████╗░██╗░░░░░░░██╗░█████╗░██████╗░██████╗░
██╔══██╗██╔══██╗██╔════╝██╔════╝░██║░░██╗░░██║██╔══██╗██╔══██╗██╔══██╗
██████╔╝███████║╚█████╗░╚█████╗░░╚██╗████╗██╔╝██║░░██║██████╔╝██║░░██║
██╔═══╝░██╔══██║░╚═══██╗░╚═══██╗░░████╔═████║░██║░░██║██╔══██╗██║░░██║
██║░░░░░██║░░██║██████╔╝██████╔╝░░╚██╔╝░╚██╔╝░╚█████╔╝██║░░██║██████╔╝
╚═╝░░░░░╚═╝░░╚═╝╚═════╝░╚═════╝░░░░╚═╝░░░╚═╝░░░╚════╝░╚═╝░░╚═╝╚═════╝░

I tried changing the font family but it did not work. Need help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So all ASCII characters have those lines by default. If you look at the images (even on the non buggy one) you see the colored lines if you zoom in. The difference is that the lines on example 2 are on white characters where the colors blend better where as on black they are more visible because nothing mixes with black. If you really want users to be able to copy the text then I'd recommend a white characters else, use an own made picture